# DOMNodeInserted behaves weird when performing DOM manipulation on body

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

The following code uses `DOMNodeInserted` to perform DOM manipulation on the `body` element once it is inserted into the DOM. I know `$(document).ready(function {  });` is enough to do the job, but I want to test the `DOMNodeInserted` event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function DOMmanipulation() {
            if (document.body) {
                document.removeEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', DOMmanipulation);
                // DOM manipulation start
                document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="wrapper">' + document.body.innerHTML + '</div>';
                // DOM manipulation end
            }
        }
        if (document.addEventListener) {
            document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', DOMmanipulation);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the DOM manipulation is to wrap all `innerHTML` of `body` into `<div class="wrapper"></div>`.

It does work. However, a weird thing happened. If you use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tool to inspect the manipulated `body`, you can find that there was a mysterious element being added. It is:

```
<div style="padding: 0px; margin: 1px 0px 0px; border: 0px none; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; position: static; top: 0px;"></div>
```

And despite the success of the manipulation, Firebug shows this error:

- Node was not found   (jquery.min.js  line 2)

And Chrome Developer Tool shows this error:

- Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8   (jquery.min.js  line 2)

But if the manipulation is just adding className, there is no error:

```
document.body.className += ' js';
```

The most weird thing is, if you remove the jQuery reference, the event won't work. Does that mean the native `DOMNodeInserted` event sometimes needs jQuery to work?

By the way, if the DOM manipulation is using jQuery syntax:

```
$('body').wrapInner('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
```

Then the mysterious element becomes more weird:

```
<div style="padding: 0px; margin: 1px 0px 0px; border: 0px; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; position: static; top: 0px; zoom: 1; ">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding: 0px; margin: 1% 0px 0px; border: 0px; visibility: hidden; ">
        <div style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); display: block; overflow: hidden; ">
            <div style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; display: block; overflow: hidden; "></div>
        </div>
        <table style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:1px;height:1px;padding:0;margin:0;border:5px solid #000;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

To sum up, we can see three issues from the above experiment:

- weird element(s) being added
- an error occurred despite the success of the DOM manipulation
- `DOMNodeInserted` sometimes seems to need jQuery to work

Any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery starts some tests when it has been loaded (line 1537 in the un-minified version)

```
// Run tests that need a body at doc ready
jQuery(function() {
var container, outer, inner, table, td, offsetSupport,
...
```

For this it adds a `div` element with some stylings. That is your `mysterious` element you've found.

Because of your event handler, this element gets wrapped within another `div`. At line 1654 jQuery wants to remove their test element with

```
body.removeChild( container );
```

which failes because the `container` isn't a child element of body anymore.

**Edit**
In your example you're not adding an element to the DOM so the event can't fire ;)

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));  // will fire DOMNodeInserted
}
```

Why it "works" with jQuery? Because jQuery adds an element to the DOM (the mysterious test element) :)

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for explaining this issue!